# OSX 10.1.2 XAMPP database errors after upgrade

Tags: mysql, database, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

Yesterday I updated osx to 10.1.2, today I was working on a project and the mysql server was not running, after several times to try to start the served I tried to reinstall xampp. Now the mysql server is working but my databases on phpmyadmin looks broken. This is how it looks
[image]

I can see the database name, on the left I can see the tables but when I click on a table it says that doesn't exists (and you can see the text "No tables found in database").

In `Xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql` there are folders with the name of my databases, and inside each folder, there are files with the name of the tables (all the tables, also the table author in the picture) with extensions `.frm` and `.ibd`.

If I open my terminal and run `show databases;` from the mysqli cli, it shows only two databases: `information_schema` and `test`, looks like there are no databases here....or I am doing the wrong thing...

Is it possible to restore databases and tables?